# How to integrate over all intervals?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to implement euler-method, runge-kutta, and middle-point-method in python's numpy.

I want to implement a function integrateall, which depending on the method (euler, runge-kutta or middle-point) integrates over all intervals. The other functions (euler, rk4 and middlepoint) must do just one step and return values.

Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def oneStepProcess(y, t, h, ode):
    ''' 
    just to represents the form that one-step-processes that follow (euler, rk4 and middlepoint) should have 
    :param y: last calculated value at time t; y_k hast n components 
      y is an np.array
    :param t: time t of last calculated step 
    :param h: timestep
    :param ode: ode to solve as function
    :return: y_new Solution at time t_{new}=t+h (as np.array)
    '''

def euler(y, t, h, ode):
    y_new = y + ode(t, y)*h
    return y_new

def f1(t, y):
    return -5*y


def fn(t, y):
    dy = np.zeros_like(y)
    dy[0] = -5*y[1]
    dy[1] = 3*y[0]+y[1]
    return dy


assert np.allclose(euler(np.array([1.]), 1., 0.1, f1), np.array([0.5]))
assert np.allclose(euler(np.array([1., -1]), 1., 0.2, fn), np.array([2, -0.6]))


def middlepoint(y, t, h, ode):
    mid_step = 0.5*h
    y_mid = y + (mid_step*ode(t, y))
    ynew = y + h*ode(y_mid, t+mid_step)
    return ynew

def rk4(y, t, h, ode):
    mid_step = 0.5*h
    k1 = y
    k2 = ode(t+mid_step, y+(mid_step*k1))
    k3 = ode(t+mid_step, y+(mid_step*k2))
    k4 = ode(t+h, y+(h*k3))
    ynew = y + (h*((k1/6)+(k2/3)+(k3/3)+(k4/6)))
    return ynew

def integrateall(method, ode, y0, t0, tend, N, intermediate=False):
    """

    :param method: one-step-process
    :param ode: RHS of ode 
    :param y0: Start value 
    :param t0: Start time
    :param tend: End time
    :param N: Number of steps
    :param intermediate: True, if we want to show intermediate solutions when plotting 
    :return: Solution at endtime (or solution AND intermediate times, if intermediate=True)
    """

    tvals = [t0]
    yvals = [y0]
    t = t0
    y = y0
    h = (tend-t0/N)
    while t < tend:
        h = min(h, tend-t)
        #t ,y = method(yvals[-1],tvals[-1],h,ode)
        t ,y = method(y,t,h,ode)
        tvals.append(t)
        yvals.append(y)

    yend = yvals[-1]
    print(yvals)

    if intermediate:
        return np.array(yvals), np.array(tvals)
    else:
        return yend


def mouse(t, y):
    dy = np.array([1 - (y[0]+y[1]), y[0]-y[1]])
    return dy

def fsimple(t, y):
    return t, y

y= integrateall(euler, fsimple, np.array([1.,]), 0., 1., 100, False) 

# wanted to test the numpy-functions 'euler', 'rk4' and 'middlepoint' in 'integrateall' with the functions fsimple, mouse, f1 and fn but none works. Just left the first one (fsimple) for clarity. If you could help me why euler, rk4 and middlepoint are not working with 'integrateall' as well, it would be perfect!
```

Here is the error Im getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6624311b1e40> in <module>()
     90     return t, y
     91 
---> 92 y= integrateall(euler, fsimple, np.array([1.,]), 0., 1., 100, False)
     93 

<ipython-input-17-6624311b1e40> in integrateall(method, ode, y0, t0, tend, N, intermediate)
     71         h = min(h, tend-t)
     72         #t ,y = method(yvals[-1],tvals[-1],h,ode)
---> 73         t ,y = method(y,t,h,ode)
     74         tvals.append(t)
     75         yvals.append(y)

<ipython-input-17-6624311b1e40> in euler(y, t, h, ode)
     17 
     18 def euler(y, t, h, ode):
---> 19     y_new = y + ode(t, y)*h
     20     return y_new
     21 

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

"fsimple" should return an array

```
def fsimple(t, y):
    return np.array([t, y])
```

because `(t,y)` cannot be multiplied element-wise by the step `h` in the method `euler`.

EDIT: The conventions for argument order and return values were not consistent in the code. See in line comments for the changes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def oneStepProcess(y, t, h, ode):
    ''' 
    just to represents the form that one-step-processes that follow (euler, rk4 and middlepoint) should have 
    :param y: last calculated value at time t; y_k hast n components 
      y is an np.array
    :param t: time t of last calculated step 
    :param h: timestep
    :param ode: ode to solve as function
    :return: y_new Solution at time t_{new}=t+h (as np.array)
    '''

def euler(y, t, h, ode):
    y_new = y + ode(y, t)*h # Fix argument order
    return y_new

def f1(y, t): # Fix argument order
    return -5*y


def fn(y, t): # Fix argument order
    dy = np.zeros_like(y)
    dy[0] = -5*y[1]
    dy[1] = 3*y[0]+y[1]
    return dy


assert np.allclose(euler(np.array([1.]), 1., 0.1, f1), np.array([0.5]))
assert np.allclose(euler(np.array([1., -1]), 1., 0.2, fn), np.array([2, -0.6]))


def middlepoint(y, t, h, ode):
    mid_step = 0.5*h
    y_mid = y + (mid_step*ode(y, t)) # Fix argument order
    ynew = y + h*ode(y_mid, t+mid_step)
    return ynew

def rk4(y, t, h, ode):
    mid_step = 0.5*h
    k1 = y
    k2 = ode(y+(mid_step*k1), t+mid_step) # Fix argument order
    k3 = ode(y+(mid_step*k2), t+mid_step) # Fix argument order
    k4 = ode(y+(h*k3), t+mid_step) # Fix argument order
    ynew = y + (h*((k1/6)+(k2/3)+(k3/3)+(k4/6)))
    return ynew

def integrateall(method, ode, y0, t0, tend, N, intermediate=False):
    """

    :param method: one-step-process
    :param ode: RHS of ode 
    :param y0: Start value 
    :param t0: Start time
    :param tend: End time
    :param N: Number of steps
    :param intermediate: True, if we want to show intermediate solutions when plotting 
    :return: Solution at endtime (or solution AND intermediate times, if intermediate=True)
    """

    tvals = [t0]
    yvals = [y0]
    t = t0
    y = y0
    h = (tend-t0)/N # Here, the whole time interval must be divided by N
    while t < tend:
        y = method(y,t,h,ode) # Fix argument order *and* remove t from the return value
        t += h
        tvals.append(t)
        yvals.append(y)

    yend = yvals[-1]
    print(yvals)

    if intermediate:
        return np.array(yvals), np.array(tvals)
    else:
        return yend


def mouse(y, t): # Fix argument order
    dy = np.array([1 - (y[0]+y[1]), y[0]-y[1]])
    return dy

def fsimple(y, t): # Fix argument order
    return y # Remove t from the return value
```

Comment: sure? Because the output is weird when I change it like that. Here is the output: [array([ 1.]), 2.0]
When I change the same in mouse, f1 and fn, they still dont work and  I get an error. integrateall should work for all of 3 funtions: euler, rk4 and middlepoint and for all of 4 ODEs fsimple, mouse, f1 and fn

Comment: any idea @Pierre?

Comment: Ok ok, you must separate things out properly between what variables are arrays and what variables are scalar. I'll check the full code right now.

Comment: So, there is another issue: the "prototype" for your right-hand-side is to take as arguments "y, t" and you mix it up in several places. Then, the rhs should return "y" and not "t, y".